# Different results in same elements that get text value from classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my site I defined a `Dictionary` that returns `Persian` or `English` strings depending on session. Here is the code for my dictionary:

```
public static string Find_Term(string term)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("Accommodation Barges", "بارج اقامتی");
    dictionary.Add("Bulk Carriers", "فله بر");
    dictionary.Add("Barge", "بارج");
    dictionary.Add("Cable Layers", "کابل گذار");
    dictionary.Add("Cargo Ships", "باربری");
    dictionary.Add("Container Ships", "کانتینر بر");
    dictionary.Add("Crew Boats", "پرسنل بر");
    dictionary.Add("Cruise Ships", "کروز");
    dictionary.Add("Dive Boats", "قایق قواصی");
    dictionary.Add("Drilling Rigs", "سکوی حفاری");
    dictionary.Add("Fishing Boat", "ماهیگیری");
    dictionary.Add("Ferries", "فری");
    dictionary.Add("Floating Cranes", "کرن شناور");
    dictionary.Add("Floating Hotels", "هتل شناور");
    dictionary.Add("Glass Bottom Boats", "کف شیشه ای");
    dictionary.Add("Hovercraft", "هاورکرافت");
    dictionary.Add("Hydrofoils", "Hydrofoils");
    dictionary.Add("Ice Breakers", "یخ شکن");
    dictionary.Add("Life Boats", "لایف بوت");
    dictionary.Add("Landing Craft", "لندینگ کرافت");
    dictionary.Add("Life Rafts", "لایف رافت");
    dictionary.Add("Passenger Boats", "مسافر بر");
    dictionary.Add("Patrol Boats", "گشت");
    dictionary.Add("Pilot Boats", "پایلوت بوت");
    dictionary.Add("Platforms", "پلتفرم");
    dictionary.Add("Research Vessels", "تحقیقاتی");
    dictionary.Add("Salvage Ships", "از رده خارج");
    dictionary.Add("Supply Boats", "ساپلای بوت");
    dictionary.Add("Support Vessels", "ساپورت بوت");
    dictionary.Add("Tankers", "تانکر");
    dictionary.Add("Tour Boats", "تور");
    dictionary.Add("Towboats", "هدایت کننده");
    dictionary.Add("Tugs", "یدک کش");
    dictionary.Add("Utility Boats", "یوتیلیتی بوت");
    dictionary.Add("All Types", "همه نوع");
    dictionary.Add("LogIn", "ورود");
    dictionary.Add("Register", "ثبت نام");
    dictionary.Add("LogOut", "خروج");
    dictionary.Add("Home", "صفحه اصلی");
    dictionary.Add("News", "تازه ها");
    //dictionary.Add("Builder", "سازنده");
    dictionary.Add("Builder", "سازنده");
    dictionary.Add("Request this vessel", "درخواست این شناور");
    dictionary.Add("Ship Particular", "مشخصات شناور");
    dictionary.Add("Build Year", "سال ساخت");

    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Lang"].ToString() == "fa")
    {
        return dictionary[term];
    }
    else
    {
        return term;

    }
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}
```

the returned string is being used for text attribute of key elements in web site. for example as below it works fine on a button located in an repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="vslCat" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# Dict.Find_Term(Eval("vCat").ToString()) %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Request.RawUrl + "?vslCat=" + Eval("vCat") %>' CssClass="ui-btn ui-mini ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

but in the same element out side of the repeater it returns nothing without error!!!

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# Dict.Find_Term("All Types")%>' CssClass="ui-btn ui-mini ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r" PostBackUrl="~/Default2.aspx" ID="btnCatAllen"></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="vslCat" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# Dict.Find_Term(Eval("vCat").ToString()) %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Request.RawUrl + "?vslCat=" + Eval("vCat") %>' CssClass="ui-btn ui-mini ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

I don't know what is the problem!!! please let me know if you find any clues.

Comment: <%# Dict.Find_Term(Eval("vCat") using when you want to bind list to any ListView so if you want to use it out of any list view, it's better using this <%=

Comment: yeah dear peyman in text attribute it dose not work. and my    <%# Eval(... is used inside a repeater with a data adapter.

Comment: oh I figured it out. outside of elements not showing data from server instead of using # Eval in attribute I should use = Eval in html section between opening and closing tags. and I figured it out by help of dear #Peyman

Comment: are you getting the desired output when using = ?

Comment: yes in <element text='<%# code%>'></element> we should use like <element text=""><%= code%></element>

Comment: If you solved your problem, you should probably post your solution and accept it as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we are using code block like `<% %>` in Elements attributes like `<asp:Button runat="server" text='<%# ...Codes... %>'></asp:Button>` outside of any element that uses a data sources, like list view or an repeater, we should use the elements id and give it a go in code behind orrrrr we should do it like:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigationUrl="#"><%= ...Codes... %></asp:HyperLink>
```

please note that the beginning of code block has changed from `#` to `=`!!!